# Sum up rows containing exact characters in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this. I want to sum up special rows containing exact characters that matched my targets.

```
             Ko_EC  FPKM  count
0          1.1.1.1  16.7      1
1         1.1.1.15  30.0      7
2        4.2.1.128  40.5      9
3         4.2.1.12  57.0     10
4  3.2.1.1 1.1.1.1  22.0      4
```

**Here are my dataframe and my targets.**

```
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#########
classes = [('1.1.1.1', 16.7, 1),
         ('1.1.1.15', 30, 7),
         ('4.2.1.128', 40.5, 9),
         ('4.2.1.12', 57, 10),
         ('3.2.1.1 1.1.1.1', 22, 4)]
labels = ['Ko_EC','FPKM', 'count']
alls = pd.DataFrame.from_records(classes, columns=labels)

target_list = ['1.1.1.1', '4.2.1.128', '4.2.1.12; 1.1.1.15; 3.2.1.1', '1.1.1.15']
```

**I want to sum up the `alls['Ko_EC']` rows containing exact characters that matched the unique `target_list`.**

Based on the answer to a previous question, I used this code:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for target in target_list:
    mask = alls.apply(lambda x: any([cls in target for cls in x['Ko_EC'].split(' ')]),
                      axis=1)
    target_sum = alls.loc[mask,["FPKM", 'count']].sum().reset_index().rename(columns={0:target}).iloc[:,1:]
    result = pd.concat([result,target_sum], axis=1) #concat as result

result = result.T
result.columns = ['FPKM', 'Count']
```

**It results like:**

```
                              FPKM  Count
1.1.1.1                       38.7    5.0
4.2.1.128                     97.5   19.0
4.2.1.12; 1.1.1.15; 3.2.1.1  125.7   22.0
1.1.1.15                      68.7   12.0
```

**What I want is**

```
                              FPKM  Count
1.1.1.1                       38.7    5.0
4.2.1.128                     40.5    9.0
4.2.1.12; 1.1.1.15; 3.2.1.1  109.0   21.0
1.1.1.15                      30.0    7.0
```

Here, the `4.2.1.128` row `FPKM` `Count` only sum that of itself, and `4.2.1.12; 1.1.1.15; 3.2.1.1` rows sum that of `4.2.1.12`, `1.1.1.15` and `3.2.1.1 1.1.1.1` in origin `alls` dataframe, but my code confused the characters `1.1.1.1`/`1.1.1.15` and `4.2.1.128`/`4.2.1.12`, because of their similarity.

Could anyone tell me how to do this and why my code cannot work? Thanks!

Comment: Pandas has a built-in `.isin()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a double [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
# create a reference from target_list
ref = (pd.Series(target_list, name='Ko_EC')
         .str.split(r';\s*')
         .explode()
         .reset_index()
       )

# merge the exploded "alls" then aggregate
out = (
  ref.merge(alls.assign(Ko_EC=alls['Ko_EC'].str.split()).explode('Ko_EC'), how='left')
     .groupby('index')
     .agg({'Ko_EC': '; '.join,
           'FPKM': 'sum',
           'count': 'sum'})
 )

print(out)
```

*NB. You can use a single pipeline, I split it in two for clarity.*

Output:

```
                             Ko_EC   FPKM  count
index                                           
0                 1.1.1.1; 1.1.1.1   38.7      5
1                        4.2.1.128   40.5      9
2      4.2.1.12; 1.1.1.15; 3.2.1.1  109.0     21
3                         1.1.1.15   30.0      7
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

for each `target` in `target_list`, create a regex pattern from `target` to find the all the rows which contains the target values then `sum` all such rows and `yield` the result

```
def func():
    for target in target_list:
        pat = r'\b(?:%s)\b' % target.replace('; ', '|')
        mask = alls['Ko_EC'].str.contains(pat, na=False)
        yield alls[mask].sum(numeric_only=True).to_frame(target).T


result = pd.concat(func())
```

### Result

```
                              FPKM  count
1.1.1.1                       38.7    5.0
4.2.1.128                     40.5    9.0
4.2.1.12; 1.1.1.15; 3.2.1.1  109.0   21.0
1.1.1.15                      30.0    7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) :

```
df_idx = alls.set_index("Ko_EC").loc[lambda x: x.index.isin(target_list)]
d_map = {a.strip():b for b in target_list for a in b.split(";") if ";" in b}
​
out = (alls
        .assign(Ko_EC= alls["Ko_EC"].str.split())
        .explode("Ko_EC").replace({"Ko_EC": d_map})
        .groupby("Ko_EC").sum(numeric_only=True)
        .combine_first(df_idx).reset_index()
      )
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

                         Ko_EC   FPKM  count
0                      1.1.1.1   38.7      5
1                     1.1.1.15   30.0      7
2                    4.2.1.128   40.5      9
3  4.2.1.12; 1.1.1.15; 3.2.1.1  109.0     21
```